# CarouselPage change current page

Tags: xamarin

App.xaml.cs

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home());
```

Home.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class Home : CarouselPage
{
    public Home()
    {
        Children.Add(new CarPage1());
        Children.Add(new CarPage2());
        CurrentPage = new CarPage2();
    }
}
```

CarPage2.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class CarPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public CarPage2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
        //I wanna change screen to CarPage1 without use Navigation.PushAsync(new CarPage1());
    }
}
```

How to change current screen to CarPage1 not use Navigation.PushAsync ?

Comment: Set the CurrentPage property

Comment: at CarPage2.xaml.cs don't work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a sample to test and setting the CurrentPage property worked correctly, you can try the following code:

```
public partial class CarPage2 : ContentPage
{
public CarPage2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var home = this.Parent as CarouselPage;
    home.CurrentPage = home.Children[0];
}
}
```